# React: mutating state with ++

Tags: reactjs

I keep getting a "don´t mutate" warning when using SetState with "++" (for instance, this.state.counter++) which I don´t  get it when I set it with "+1". Why does this happen?

Comment: the state should only be mutated using `setState`. Since you're trying to set the state, you can use variable assignment to obtain the previous value in order to modify it: `let {counter} = this.state; this.setState({ counter: counter++ })`

Remember that the `++` will only increment the value after the operation has ended, something worth considering if you run into other incrementation errors

Comment: I got the error while USING SetState.

Comment: that's because you should be using `setState` not `SetState`. What did the error say?

Comment: @EternalDoubter could you post your example code where you get this warning please?

Answer (score 3):

`this.state.counter++` expression increments `this.state.counter` and returns incremented value. `this.state.counter + 1` expression only returns incremented value.
To avoid any other collisions you should not set new state based on `this.state`. Use this code instead:

```
this.setState(old => ({counter: old.counter + 1}))
```

Check https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Thank you. I got the warning using that syntax.